# Can all notebooks record from the sound card?

Tags: laptop, sound-card, audio-recording

Is it possible that a modern notebook (say built in the last 5 years) contains a (onboard) sound card that it is not possible to record from?

I've always assumed that this is a very basic capability, but since I can't get it to work, I would like to check that before I put any more effort into it.

In case it matters, my notebook is an ASUS UL50VT, I'm trying with Sound Recorder and Audacity under Ubuntu, but I am, at this point, not asking for "Try that"-support or software recommendations.

Answer (score 2):

Well what are the 3.5mm jacks available to you, is there just the headphone jack? Is there a mic jack? Is there a sound capture jack? If it's just the headphone jack then the answer is very likely to be no, you can't capture, and to be honest apart from a microphone connector I havn't seen many input jacks on laptops.

Comment: There is a headphone jack and a microphone jack.

Comment: So it should record. Look in "Sound configuration" and "audio hardware" to set it (at least) to "Analogic Duplex Stereo" or something with "any_output_you_use + Analogic Input". There are settings where the input jack is not used. Obs you can usually access Sound config with `pavucontrol` on terminal if you can't find it near the indicators

Comment: @laurent: Maybe you misread my question. I don't want to record the outside world but the sound the soundcard produces, directly, without using a cable.